# Noisy top peak of clock signal with CMOS inverter circuit

Tags: inverter, cmos, crystal

I have built this clock circuit (with a 4MHz crystal rather than the 1Mhz shown in the image):

[image: circuit]

I am concerned about the wave form that I see on my scope. It doesn't look very clean on the top (see image below). I plan to use this as a clock for driving a microprocessor. My question is whether this wave form is 'good enough'? Also, an observation: this noise at the top seems to be caused by some sort of interference. When I physically come closer to the circuit (lean in), the wave form suddenly becomes clean (see second image below). But then after a couple of seconds it starts 'bleeding' the noise and stabilizes into wave form shown in the first image. I am not sure what is going on exactly.

[image: scope image - stable wave form]

[image]

**Update**

A few comments suggested changing the duration per division on the scope. Setting this to 2ms/div does indeed show some strange ripple:

[image]

I disconnected the clock circuit and measured the power supply directly and it too shows a ripple at 2ms/div. So looks like this is a power supply issue? :|

**Update 2**
It indeed was the power supply. Swapped it out with a 5v Apple iPhone charger and now I'm getting a clean, stable clock signal! Thanks to everyone for the help in debugging this.

Comment: When you lean in, do you touch any cable/connector/etc.?

Comment: No I don't touch anything.

Comment: The first trace look like there is a much lower frequency signal mixed in. Try setting the scope to a much slower timebase to see if you can pick it out.

Comment: Did you build on breadboard? Are there any bypass caps? Are there long wires from 5V supply?

Comment: @KevinWhite I zoomed in and out and I cannot identify any standout frequencies. Is there anything specific I should be looking for? Also, shouldn't the extra frequency manifest both at top and bottom? This noise I'm seeing is only at the top.

Comment: @Justme it is on a protoboard, but yes I've tried adding caps across the rails and moving  the components closer. Not seeing any changes.

Comment: What happens on the supply voltage when you lean in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the scope trigger to "LINE". And drop the sweep to 2 milli Seconds per division. This may reveal the cause.

Otherwise, slow the sweep to 10 microSeconds/divison, and set the trigger to DC Internal, then adjust the trigger level to be near the waveform top.
This may reveal SwitchReg ripple.

As the comments suggest, have 0.1uF cap across VDD/GND within 1cm of the oscillator.

And have your scope probe Ground lead going to the bottom of that Scope Ground lead.

Other circuits sharing the VDD, such as MCU, thru long leads/wires to the power supply may cause this. But the smoothness of the waveform's top suggests there is no high_frequency energy here.

Comment: I set the 2 ms/div and it indeed reveals 'something' :o But I can't make much sense of it. Here is the picture of the trace: https://ibb.co/dQvHMTD

Comment: I disconnected the clock circuit and measured the power supply directly and it too shows a ripple at 2ms/div. So looks like this is a power supply issue? :|

Comment: I just swapped the power supply with a 5v iPhone charger and now I'm getting a clean, stable trace. Thanks for helping debug this!

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is OK and the noise is probably a measurement artifact and/or there is some feedback on your protoboard.

With the same circuit on a PCB and decoupling capacitors in place the signal should look "clean" like in the 2nd photo.

> My question is whether this wave form is 'good enough'?

Yes it will be, a microcontroller clock input will only "look" at the voltage "in the middle" so around Vcc / 2. If it is above that it will see it as a high, below that as low. Even with the noise, the signal stays well above Vcc / 2 so the microcontroller will completely ignore that noise.

But as said, this is a measurement artifact and the signal will be clean when you put it on a PCB so there's no reason to worry.

If you have the 74HC04 sitting in a socket then there's something else you can try, that is to use a **slower** inverters like the 4069 (HEF4069, CD4069 etc).

Another thing to try is changing the value of R1, try 10 Mohm and see what you get.